# Nexus 6P - Fix "No Command" with a broken volume button

Tags: google, nexus-6p, nexus, 7.1-nougat

So, I have broken my Volume Up button. And my phone has gone into a "No Command" mode that does not let me turn my phone on.

Since my volume up is stuck and not working, how do I reset the phone so that I can go back to using it? I am able to get to the reboot screen by pressing the Power and Volume Down. But cannot proceed further because my Volume Up does not work.

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: is USB Debugging enabled?

Comment: did you get it fixed? I have the exact same situation right now